# multiple URL in mule

Tags: mule

the below URL's need to be call one after other how to configure in Mule?

```
Currently I am using HTTP requester where i am able to call first URL by 
passing URI and query param.

My question is how to call another 2 URL one after other?

i have defined in property file as:

Myday.contextpath.getURL1 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_All_Domains_-_All_Domains
Myday.contextpath.getURL2 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_INT93-_All_Domains
Myday.contextpath.getURL3 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_RPT_D_
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your array as an expression in the properties file, so:

```
Myday.contextpath.getUrls [ "http://url1" , "http://url2" , "http://url3" ]
```

Then use `${Myday.contextpath.getUrls}` in a for each scope's collection expression.